# Binary search tree recursive display function, not sure how it works?

Tags: c++

I have a BST and I found this function online, which prints it in the correct order, but I don't understand how.

```
void display()
{
    inOrder(root);
}
void inOrder(treeNode* n)
{
   classA foo;
   if (n != NULL)
   {
        inOrder(n->left);
        foo = *n->item;
        cout << foo << endl << endl;
        inOrder(n->right);
    }
 }
```

I initialize each node's left and right to NULL. Why does the if statement continue after a NULL pointer is sent in, and where does it continue from?

Comment: Well if `root` isn't `null` it does what it says failing in both `right` and `left` on the first attempt. It prints in the correct order because of the tree structure. Left is "smaller" than its root so it runs down the left first. If that helps any.

Comment: You have 2 calls of the inOrder function inside the body.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have the following BST:

[image]

When `inOrder` is called with this BST,

**Recursion level 0**

`n` points to `8`. So you enter the block:

```
    inOrder(n->left);
    foo = *n->item;
    cout << foo << endl << endl;
    inOrder(n->right);
```

`inOrder` is called using `n->left` as argument, which is node `3`.

**Recursion level 1**

`n` points to `3`. So you enter the same code block.

`inOrder` is called using `n->left` as argument, which is node `1`.

**Recursion level 2**

`n` points to `1`. So you enter the same code block.

`inOrder` is called using `n->left` as argument, which is `NULL`.

**Recursion level 3**

`n` points to `NULL`. So you do not enter the above code block. You simply return from the function. Now are back in the next statement in the previous recursion level.

**Recursion level 2**

The following lines are executed:

```
    foo = *n->item;
    cout << foo << endl << endl;
    inOrder(n->right);
```

You print `1`. Then, `inOrder` is called using `n->right` as argument, which is `NULL`.

**Recursion level 3**

`n` points to `NULL`. So you do not enter the above code block. You simply return from the function. Now are back in the next statement in the previous recursion level.

**Recursion level 2**

There are no more lines to execute. The function simply returns to previous recursion level.

**Recursion level 1**

The following lines are executed:

```
    foo = *n->item;
    cout << foo << endl << endl;
    inOrder(n->right);
```

You print `3`. Then, `inOrder` is called using `n->right` as argument, which is node `6`.

You can now follow this step by step all the way. The end result is that you will end up printing the numbers in the following order.

```
1
3
4
6
7
8
10
13
14
```